# SDK 25.1.0 crash on CommitNow when call within onBackStackChanged(). Google Bug?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity, with 2 fragments `FragmentMainOne` and `FragmentMainTwo`  that will swap whenever `onBackStackChanged()` is called

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int count = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        loadFragment();

        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
                new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBackStackChanged() {
                        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
                            loadFragment();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    public void loadSubFragment() {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.view_container,
                new FragmentSubOne(), FragmentSubOne.TAG).addToBackStack(FragmentSubOne.TAG).commit();
    }

    public void loadFragment() {
        count++;
        if (count % 2 == 1) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.view_container,
                    new FragmentMainOne(), FragmentMainOne.TAG).commitNow();
        } else {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.view_container,
                    new FragmentMainTwo(), FragmentMainTwo.TAG).commitNow();
        }
    }
}
```

The codes works well before upgrade to SDK 25.1.0. (i.e okay in 25.0.0 and earlier).

After upgrade to SDK 25.1.0, upon `onBackStackChanged()`, it will crash on `commitNow()` with

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.elyeproj.commitissue, PID: 3876
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:1946)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1965)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:614)
                  at com.elyeproj.commitissue.MainActivity.loadFragment(MainActivity.java:45)
                  at com.elyeproj.commitissue.MainActivity$1.onBackStackChanged(MainActivity.java:27)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.reportBackStackChanged(FragmentManager.java:2409)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2157)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2092)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:822)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:775)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:178)
```

It also works fine if I switch `commitNow()` to `commit()`. Is this a bug on the latest SDK, or something I miss?

Note the full code could be access to replicate the issue https://github.com/elye/issue_commitnow_sdk25_1_0
(Just load the App, click on "GO TO SUBFRAGMENT", and then click "Back"... the crash happens.)

Comment: I think it is fine because when `onBackStackChanged()` is called the fragmentManager is still doing transaction and you are trying to do one more transaction when manager is still doing transaction.`commitNow()` is nothing but like calling `executePendingTransactions()` after commit. So only two options, 1. Use `commit()` 2. put your transaction in messageQueue using `someView.Post(new Runnable() {})`.

Comment: Thanks @AkshayBhat'AB'. I have dig and found the reason, and match with your explanation as well. I have post an answer to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After investigation, looks like this is a new constraint introduced in Support Library 25.1.0.

The crash happens on

```
private void ensureExecReady(boolean allowStateLoss) {
    if (mExecutingActions) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("FragmentManager is already executing transactions");
    }
    // ... more codes
}
```

So something has set the `mExecutingActions` to true.

Found out that in 25.1.0 FragmentManager class, the codes below is new

```
private boolean popBackStackImmediate(String name, int id, int flags) {
    execPendingActions();
    ensureExecReady(true);

    boolean executePop = popBackStackState(mTmpRecords, mTmpIsPop, name, id, flags);
    if (executePop) {
        mExecutingActions = true;
        try {
            optimizeAndExecuteOps(mTmpRecords, mTmpIsPop);
        } finally {
            cleanupExec(); // setting mExecutingAction = false
        }
    }

    doPendingDeferredStart();
    return executePop;
}
```

Where it set the `mExecutingActions` to true when popping the fragment stack. This is not set before 25.1.0. I view this as explicit introduce prevention to ensure backstack popping is complete before on commit another fragment.

To workaround the issue, just us `commit()` instead if `commitNow()`.

For more illustration of the issue, refers to https://medium.com/@elye.project/new-in-support-library-25-1-0-android-disallow-commitnow-on-onbackstackchanged-227c651eefb2#.p9ds8m8ws